# Let $P_q=\{y^2 \mod q \; \mid y\in Z\}$.How do I show $|P_{pq}|=|P_p|\cdot|P_q| \; \;$ where $gcd(p,q)=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $P_q=\{y^2 \mod q \; \mid y\in Z\}$.How do I show $|P_{pq}|=|P_p|\cdot|P_q| \; \;$ where $gcd(p,q)=1$

I thought of the map:

$f: P_{pq} \to P_p \times P_q$

$f(y^2 \mod pq) = (y^2 \mod p,\; y^2 \mod q)$

Comment: Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @Dzoooks I proved both well defined and injection. can you tell me how to prove surjection

Comment: The surjection is exactly the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @Dzoooks if $(a^2  \mod p, b^2 \mod q) \in P_p \times P_q$, then it what is its preimage ? I can't think of it. for Chinese remainder, I need $a^2$ in both components

Comment: @Dzoooks It would really mean a lot if you could add a detailed answer for onto part. Right now am confused

Comment: [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)